# Exported FBX is Mapped Incorrectly

Tags: texturing, .fbx, vector-mapping

so I've imported this coffee shop that I've created in blender in exported it as fbx with embedded textures , but the mapping of those textures is completely missed up , I'm using an Object Vector map instead of a UV one , whats the solution ?
[image: first photo is from blender, second from window's 3d viewer,and the last is from unity (all of them use the same materials and textures)]

Comment: You said it: you need to use UV. Object vector is very software specific and may not be supported in other softwares. Don’t worry, UV unwrapping is actually rather simple, especially with a simple square mesh like this.

Comment: THNX , I'll try it :D